# Как вывести в label.Text "string" значение (Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#

Всем привет, подскажите как вывести стринговое значение (string) в label.Text (C#, Visual Studio 2017, Windows Form Application);

```
 int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        int sot = n / 100;
        int des = n % 100 / 10;
        int ed = n % 10;

        switch (sot)
        {
            case 1:
                string n1 = "Сто";
                break;
            case 2:
                 n1 = "Двести";
                break;
            case 3:
                 n1 = "Триста";
                break;
            case 4:
                 n1 = "Четыриста";
                break;
            case 5:
                 n1 = "Пятьсот";
                break;
            case 6:
                 n1 = "Шестьсот";
                break;
            case 7:
                 n1 = "Семьсот";
                break;
            case 8:
                 n1 = "Восемьсот";
                break;
            case 9:
                 n1 = "Девятьсот";
                break;
            case 0:
                n1 = "";
                break;
        }
        switch (des)
        {
            case 2:
                string n2 = "двадцать";
                break;
            case 3:
                n2 = "тридцать";
                break;
            case 4:
                n2 = "сорок";
                break;
            case 5:
                n2 = "пятьдесят";
                break;
            case 6:
                n2 = "шестьдесят";
                break;
            case 7:
                n2 = "семьдесят";
                break;
            case 8:
                n2 = "восемьдесят";
                break;
            case 9:
                n2 = "девяносто";
                break;
            case 0:
                n2 = "";
                break;
            case 1:
                switch (ed)
                {
                    case 0:
                         n2 = "десять";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        n2 = "одиннадцать";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        n2 = "двенадцать";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        n2 = "тринадцать";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        n2 = "четырнадцать";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        n2 = "пятнадцать";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        n2 = "шестнадцать";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        n2 = "семнадцать";
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        n2 = "восемнадцать";
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        n2 = "девятнадцать";
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        switch(ed)
            {
            case 1:
                string n3 = "один";
                break;
            case 2:
                n3 = "два";
                break;
            case 3:
                n3 = "три";
                break;
            case 4:
                n3 = "четыре";
                break;
            case 5:
                n3 = "пять";
                break;
            case 6:
                n3 = "шесть";
                break;
            case 7:
                n3 = "семь";
                break;
            case 8:
                n3 = "восемь";
                break;
            case 9:
                n3 = "девять";
                break;
            case 0:
                n3 = "";
                break;
        }
        if (des != 1)
        {
            label2.Text = n1 + n2 + n3;
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = n1 + n2;
        }
```

Я вывдил данным образом :

```
if (des != 1)
        {
            label2.Text = n1 + n2 + n3;
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = n1 + n2;
        }
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в зоне видимости переменных, а не в присвоении значения строки тексту label.

`n1`,`n2` и `n3` нужно объявить до `switch`.

```
var n1 = string.Empty;
var n2 = string.Empty;
var n3 = string.Empty;

switch(sot)...
```

Comment: Можите показать на примере пожалуйста.

Comment: @A.Balashov done